# Ruby logger is nil

Tags: ruby, logging

When I try to use Ruby's `logger`, it comes up as `nil`. Is an instance variable the correct way to do this?

```
require 'logger'

class LogStuff

  # Log to STDOUT and `tee` it to a file
  @logger = Logger.new("| tee output.log")
  @logger.level = :debug

  def run
    (1..10).each do |n|
      @logger.debug('l1') { @logger.debug "proceessing #{n}" }
    end

    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].each do |letter|
      @logger.debug('letters') { @logger.debug "proceessing #{letter}" }
    end
  end

end

if __FILE__ == $0
  lggr = LogStuff.new
  lggr.run
end
```

Error message:

```
$ ruby script.rb 
script.rb:11:in `block in run': undefined method `debug' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from script.rb:10:in `each'
        from script.rb:10:in `run'
        from script.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
def initialize
  # Log to STDOUT and `tee` it to a file
  @logger = Logger.new("| tee output.log")
  @logger.level = :debug
end
```

Obviously into the `LogStuff` class. Basically, otherwise your `@logger` variable is defined in another scope.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer lets me.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)